# how to install lando and add a plugin phpmyadmin

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, lando

I want to add phpmyadmin  in lando as a plugin but facing this error
[image: error screen of terminal]

Answer (score 0):

To add Phpmyadmin, you need to re-write `.lando.yml` file and append in the file end with the following lines.

But to have Phpmyadmin, you should have `PHP` backend or any LAMP setup, so that you can use **PHPMyAdmin**

```yaml
services:
  myservice:
    type: phpmyadmin
```

For more details on how to configure you can refer to official [documentation](https://docs.lando.dev/phpmyadmin/)

For particular `phpmyadmin` version

```yaml
services:
  myservice:
    type: phpmyadmin:4.8
```

**Another Method** : You can use **portforwarding** to connect with any external Database GUI tools like Dbeaver

By default, the default databases have portforward, check database port for connecting externally with `lando info`